# Loop doesn't update listboxes until it is done iterating

Tags: listbox, c++-cli, clr

I have a loop that takes file name from a listbox, performs a system() call, then moves that filename to another listbox. Problem is, it doesn't move the filenames over one at a time, but waits until the entire loop is finished and moves them all at once. What would I do to get it to perform how I want it to?

the loop:

```
for each( String^% file in filename )
{
    int x = convert( file );
    lbComplete->Items->Add( lbFiles->Items[0] );    // place the completed file
    lbFiles->Items->Remove( lbFiles->Items[0] );    // in the other listbox
}
```

The function convert() that contains the system call:

```
int convert( String^ file )
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string dir, fileAddress, fileName, outputDir;
    ...
    return system( ss.str().c_str() );          
}
```

Comment: Could this be an issue with a missing screen/widget refresh call between the updates?

Comment: Looks like the consensus believes so. Wasn't aware I needed to do this since I've never really worked with forms. Guess I'll go look up how

Comment: In your loop you don't give the system time to redraw your controls, you need to allow the paint events to flow in between each loop iteration if you want to see it on the screen - what call depends on what kind of UI you are using (which you haven't mentioned).

Comment: Visual C++ CLR project. A simple ListBox1->Refresh(); worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to call a refresh function at the end of your loop forcing it to redraw your listboxes otherwise it will wait until after your loop to do so.

```
for each( String^% file in filename )
{
    int x = convert( file );
    lbComplete->Items->Add( lbFiles->Items[0] );    // place the completed file
    lbFiles->Items->Remove( lbFiles->Items[0] );    // in the other listbox
    // INSERT REFRESH FUNCTION HERE
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very common in GUI programming that methods called from the "event thread" or "event loop" need to finish before the changes they make are seen on the screen.  That's regardless of the language or the environment.  The usual way to avoid that problem on the things I'm most familiar with (like Java Swing) is to do the updates outside of the event loop, but use notifications (swing events) to tell the GUI to update the display occassionally.

Answer (score 1):

Tell both listboxes to refresh themselves after moving an item.