# Hiding the console window in a system() call

Tags: console, clr, c++-cli

Continuing from **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958494/loop-doesnt-update-listboxes-until-it-is-done-iterating)**

With each system call, the function constructs a set of parameters and sends them off to another program that is just console-based. Is there a way I can make it so that no console window pops up for each call?

I've done a search but the ones that aren't a linker issue just aren't working for me. For instance, I tried the `_execl` call and `System::Diagnostics::Process^ myProcess = gcnew System::Diagnostics::Process;` but they aren't working.

The `_execl` will bring a console window up, scroll a bunch of stuff (from the program I called I guess), then close the my app and not even do what it was supposed to do.
The `System::Diagnostics::Process^ myProcess = gcnew System::Diagnostics::Process;` doesn't seem to execute what I want either because the output folder that should contain files, contains nothing.

So I'm open for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx) API gives you the control you need.  For example:

```
#include <windows.h>

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    STARTUPINFO         si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    TCHAR               cmdLine[MAX_PATH] = L"myOtherApp.exe -with -some -args";

    ::ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    ::CreateProcess(NULL, cmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    Console::ReadLine();
    return 0;
}
```

With the CreateProcess flags set to 0 as above, the secondary app does not open its own console window, and writes its output to the parent's window.  To silence the secondary app entirely, look at other [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863(v=VS.85).aspx) flags, e.g. CREATE_NO_WINDOW.